# Hamiltonian: Invariant Core

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider a Hamiltonian:
$$H:\mathcal{D}(H)\to\mathcal{H}:\quad H=H^*$$

And an operator:
$$A:\mathcal{D}(A)\to\mathcal{H}:\quad A=A^*$$

Denote its evolution by:
$$A(t):=e^{-itH}Ae^{itH}$$

Regard a core:
$$\mathcal{D}\subseteq\mathcal{D}(A):\quad\overline{A_\mathcal{D}}=A$$

Suppose it is invariant:
$$e^{itH}\mathcal{D}\subseteq\mathcal{D}$$

For their common domain:
$$\varphi,\psi\in\mathcal{D}(A)\cap\mathcal{D}(H)$$

There is a sequence:
$$\varphi_n,\psi_n\in\mathcal{D}:\quad\langle\{A(t)-A(0)\}\varphi_n,\psi_n\rangle\to\langle\{A(t)-A(0)\}\varphi,\psi\rangle$$

How can I prove this from scratch?

Comment: What do you mean by $\overline{A_\mathcal{D}}=A$? Is $\mathcal{D}$ a vector space since you write $e^{itH}\mathcal{D}\subseteq\mathcal{D}$?

Comment: @draks...: By $\overline{A_\mathcal{D}}=A$ I mean $\mathcal{D}$ is a core for $A$. Yes, $\mathcal{D}$ is supposed to be a vector space.

Comment: A matrix vector space or something like $\mathbb C^n$?

Comment: @draks...: What is a matrix vector space?!

Comment: @draks...: I assume $\mathcal{D}$ to be a subspace of $\mathcal{D}(A)$.

Comment: Think of a finite Lie Algebra as basis of the vector space spanning your hamiltonian. You operate on the matrix vector space by $e^{-itH}Ae^{itH}$. You can even write this as common vector space: $e^{-itH}Ae^{itH} \mapsto (e^{itH})^T \otimes  e^{-itH} \operatorname{vec}(A)$, where $\operatorname{vec}(A)$ is the vector you get when you stack the coloumkn ontop each other (see [superoperator formalism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29))...

Comment: @draks...: This thread deals with unbounded operators. As such they're not supposed to be everywhere defined. So you're missing even the structure of an algebra.